# Unity launcher keyboard shortcuts for "/media" mounted drives?

Tags: unity, keyboard, launcher

There are no letter/number designations for these drives. Is there any way I can select them using the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to select individual items with the keyboard, but you can report a bug (`ubuntu-bug unity`) on unity, as this would be a good improvement.

If you have the skills you can also write a patch :)!